# Update method with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

so I am trying to update an event in my project and so far i sort of have it working, i can see the input that i am inputting in the cmd but the data is not being stored in the mongodb. once i press the 'submit' button i get redirected to a page that says "not found"

This is the code for my update event page

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <h1> Update Event</h1>
        {{#if hasErrors}}
            <div class=alert alert-danger">
                {{# each messages}}
                    <p>{{this}}</p>
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}

        <form action=/user/updateEvents/{{this._id}} method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="eventName">Event Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="eventName" name="eventName" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="eventDate">Event Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="eventDate" name="eventDate" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="eventPlace">Place of Event</label>
                <input type="text" id="eventPlace" name="eventPlace" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="eventPrice">Price of Event: €</label>
                <input type="text" id="eventPrice" name="eventPrice" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update Event</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Here is my code for the update function

```
   // Update an existing student in database.
function updateEvents (req, res) {
  console.log("test")
  console.log(req.body);
  if(req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }
  Event.findById(req.params.id, function(err, event) {
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    }
    if(!event) {
      return res.send(404);
    }
    var updated = _.merge(event, req.body);
    updated.save(function(err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, event);
    });
  });
};
```

and here is my route for the function.

```
    //store the updated data in to the database 
router.post('/updateEvents',updateEvents, function(req, res, next) {
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does it log anything in your console?

Comment: You're sending it as a path param, but your server side middleware definition is not including the dynamic part. Can you try `router.post('/updateEvents/:id',...` ? Also, is this the router mounted at "/user"? Otherwise you need to include that too.

Comment: so when i have the router.post('/updateEvents/:id', ... in the cmd the data is not shown but when i remove it the data is shown.